# how to resize a ul, div p in jquery

Tags: jquery, timeline

I have a time line feature in my site, on a certain year the text maybe very long on some it may only be 1 line, i want to resize the page so that when a user clicks on the next year the page isnt really long with one line on it?

im using timeliner js from
http://www.csslab.cl/ejemplos/timelinr/latest/js/jquery.timelinr-0.9.5.js

```
 <ul id="dates">
<li><a href="#1940s">1940s</a></li>
<li><a href="#1950s">1950s</a></li>   
</ul>
<ul id="issues">
<li id="1940s"><img src="/timeline/1950.jpg" />
<h1>1940's</h1>
<p>RonaldertreRonaldertreRonaldertrevRonaldertre Ronaldertre RonaldertreRonaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertre vkv RonaldertreRonaldertre kRonaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertre Ronaldertrekv Ronaldertre RonaldertreRonaldertre Ronald &ldquo;Eddy&rdquo; Edmonson a qualified architect and surveyor joined the Royal Artillery in WW2. At the end of vre RonaldertreRonaldertre Ronald &ldquo;Eddy&rdquoWar he found himself stationed in Turin, and became interested in a nearby factory where the Germans held early experiments in plastic injection moulding. After being re RonaldertreRonaldertre Ronald &ldquo;Eddy&rdquo; Edmonson a qualified architect and surveyor joined the Royal Artillery in WW2. At the end of the War he found himself stationed in Turin, and became interested in a nearby factory where the Germans held early experiments in plastic injection moulding. After being re RonaldertreRonaldertre Ronald &ldquo;Eddy&rdquo; Edmonson a qualified architect and surveyor joined the Royal Artillery in WW2. At the end of the War he found himself stationed in Turin, and became interested in a nearby factory where the Germans held early experiments in plastic injection moulding. After being the War he found himself stationed in Turin, and became interested in a nearby factory where the Germans held early experiments in plastic injection moulding. After being Demobbed back at home, Eddy took this interest further and on 18th October 1946 set up plastic moulding company, Plastiers Limited (Lewisham). He is pictured (right) manning his first commercial production run! RonaldertreRonaldertreRonaldertreRonaldertreRonaldertrevRonaldertreRonaldertre test test test.</p>
</li>
<li id="1950s"><img src="/timeline/1960.jpg" />
<h1>1950's</h1>
<p>Eddy.</p>
</li>

</li>
</ul>
```

Example here :

http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/sEFQS/1/

EDIT:

jquery ive attempted:

```
$("#dates li a").click(function () {
        $('#issues').css("height", $("#" + $(this).html()).height());
    });
```

Comment: wut, that question is really vague...

Comment: how do i adjust the height of the page as the text changes as you go along the timeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS width & height

If you want it to be dynamic use js to check the length and update the CSS width when text changes

**Edit:**

This example is for the width.  Check your page elements for a good container that will give you the height you are looking for.

for width you can do something like

```
/* Give your paragraph an Id to be able to get them  <p id="paragraph"></p> */
var text = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML;
//alert(text.length );
$('#issues').width( text.length)
//$('#issues').height( /* preferred height goes here */)
```

then find a good measure to set the width, not necessarily the same as the string's length.

If you find a container that has the right height, just grab its height and update the other elements.

if you want to figure the height based on the text, that means you will have to predict the number of lines broken on the page.  That depends on the page layout/screen size and resolution.  So, pick a number for a screen width (maybe 1024) then check on the layout how many lines it takes to break.  You can go even more by checking all that dynamically and doing the calculations.  IMO, it should not be a complex solution, but that depends on how critical it is to you.

Sometimes, having height as 100% and putting it in place will make it take care of it self.

Comment: yes thats what i would like to do any examplles how to measure the height? i know .css('height','') i could change the height but where do i get the height to change to from?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't very clear. Why not just apply some styles to it to constrain it's width?

```
p {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden; //or other value to suit your needs
}
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sEFQS/2/

Comment: the problem is with the height not width

Comment: So do you want to cut the text if it's too tall? You can use the `overflow` property for that. See updated example.

Comment: Hi yes, i dont want that scroll there if i can avoid it

Comment: Well, what is it that you want to do? You're not specifying it clearly enough. What *exactly* do you want to happen to the text?